# Convert spherical vector field to cartesian vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates

I have a vector field defined in spherical coordinates as follows:
$$\vec{F}\big\langle\rho,\theta,\phi\big\rangle = \bigg\langle\rho  \sin\theta \cos\phi ,\rho^3 \cos \phi, \frac{\tan \theta}{\sqrt{r}}\bigg\rangle$$

And a point in the spherical coordinate system that lies on the surface of a sphere of radius 10, given by
$$ P(\rho,\theta,\phi) =\bigg (10, \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{3}\bigg)  $$

I need to find the perpendicular and parallel component of the force with respect to the surface at the point P. I was thinking of solving this by converting the vector field and the point to cartesian, find the normal vector to the sphere at point P and the field vector at point P, find the projection of the field vector on the normal vector, which gives the perpendicular component of F, and then subtract from F the perpendicular component to find the parallel component, then convert the perpendicular and parallel vector back to spherical. The issue is that I don't know how to convert the vector field (or vectors) from cartesian to spherical and vice versa. I know how to convert a point from cartesian to spherical or from spherical to cartesian, but it looks like the same process cannot be used when vectors are involved.

So my question is, how would I solve the problem using the above method. Furthermore, could someone show me how to solve it in spherical coordinates directly, if possible, with a step by step explanation. Assume I know very little about spherical coordinates and try to describe each step as clearly as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Is the target vector $\vec{F}$ represented in spherical coordinates as well? Also, when you say surface, do you mean the surface of the sphere?

Comment: Hi, yes F is represented in spherical coordinates, not cartesian, which is why I'm having some trouble with it. The surface is the surface of the sphere, more specifically the surface of the sphere at the given point (which is also in spherical).

Comment: Quick question: How is $\theta$ being defined? Is it the angle between the positive $z-$axis, or is it the angle between the positive $x-$ axis the projected input onto the $xy-$ plane? If it's the angle between the positive $z-$ axis then my calculations below need to be fixed

Comment: I'm using the physics notation, not the mathematical one, so $\theta$ is the angle between the positive x-axis of the vector projection onto the xy plane.

Comment: If you're using the physics notation then $\theta$ is the angle made with the positive $z-$ axis. Look here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I meant $\phi$ is the angle between the positive x-axis and the projection onto the xy plane. $\theta$ is the angle between the z-axis and the xy plane.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113164/discussion-between-matthew-holder-and-samuel-snerden).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's convert everything back to cartesian.

(1): The spherical point $P=\bigg(10,\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{3}\bigg)$ converts to $P=\bigg(\frac{15}{2},\frac{5\sqrt{3}}{2},5\bigg)$ in cartesian.

(2): The vector $\vec{n}=\big<3,\sqrt{3},2\big>$ is orthogonal to the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=100$ at the point $P$. (This vector $\vec{n}$ is in cartesian form).

(3): The target vector $\vec{F}(P)=\Big<\frac{5}{2},500,\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{27}}}\Big>$ expressed in spherical coordinates converts to the cartesian vector $$\vec{F}(P)=\Bigg<\frac{5}{2}\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{27}}}\bigg)\cos(500),\frac{5}{2}\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{27}}}\bigg)\sin(500),\frac{5}{2}\cos\bigg(\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{27}}}\bigg)\Bigg>$$ Knowing all this, we can now write $$\vec{F}(P)=\Big[\vec{F}(P)\Big]_{||}+\Big[\vec{F}(P)\Big]_{\perp}$$ where $\Big[\vec{F}(P)\Big]_{\perp}=\bigg(\frac{\vec{F}(P)\cdot \vec{n}}{\vec{n}\cdot \vec{n}}\bigg)\vec{n}$ is orthogonal projection of $F(\vec{P})$ onto $\vec{n}$ and $$\Big[\vec{F}(P)\Big]_{||}=F(\vec{P})-\Big[\vec{F}(P)\Big]_{\perp}$$

Comment: Hi, first of all, thank you for answering my question, that was exactly how I was planning on solving the problem, but I got stuck at the part where we convert $\vec{F}(P)=\Big<\frac{5}{2},500,\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}{\sqrt[\leftroot{-2}\uproot{2}4]{27}}}\Big>$ to cartesian. How do you convert this vector into cartesian? Is it possible to go step by step, showing me the formula used to do this? It doesn't seem to be the same formula used to convert spherical points. Also, how would I convert the tangential and parallel components back to spherical?

Comment: From what I read from different sources, a vector in spherical coordinates defined at the origin is not the same as a vector defined at a point P. So if I have the vector field F at a point P, how would I convert this vector into cartesian? It's not as simple as converting it to cartesian using the formula for points, is it? Is it correect to say the vector$\vec{F}<1,\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}>$ at the origin in spherical coordinates it not the same as the vector $\vec{F}<1,\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}>$ at a point P other than the origin?

Comment: Vectors do not have a fixed position in space. They can be located at any initial base and still be regarded at the same vector. That being said, how do you define a "vector in spherical coordinates at point $P$"? To convert $\vec{F}(P)$ back to cartesian coordinates we could just imagine that the base point of $\vec{F}(P)$ is located at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: I took the following from my textbook: "Unlike the Cartesian system,
in which the base vectors i,j,k are independent of
the location of P, in the cylindrical system both r and φ
are functions of φ". So isn't the vector's direction in cylindrical (as well as spherical) coordinates related to the point it's located at? For instance, if we give a vector in spherical coordinates, with an r, theta and phi, would the vector have the exact same components regardless of whether we start that vector from the origin or going from a point P?

Comment: Usually when I'm having trouble envisioning what's going on I like to refer to a simpler case. Let's define a vector field in *polar* coordinates by $\vec{F}(r,\theta)=(r^2/2,2\theta +\pi/6)$. How would the vector $\vec{F}(1,\pi/2)$ look like?